# Hybrid app push notification icon not showing on Android 8 (Oreo)

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, android-8.0-oreo

When sending a push notification from IBM MobileFirst server to a device with Android 8 OS, instead of showing app icon it is showing a mobile icon. Tested on Android 6(Marshmallow) and several iOS version and it is showing the correct icon. I have not tested it with Android 7(Nougat). It is a hybrid app using Cordova(7.1.0) + ReactJS.

[image: Default mobile icon is shown instead]

Comment: Check if your icon is available in all sizes in the minmap directory

Comment: Found the issue, all sizes available but IBM MobileFirst has its own default icon generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, cordova-plugin-mfp-push plugin provides default notification icon *name push_notification_icon.png* which is not from standard Android minmap. I used  in config.xml and specified src="my icon location path" and target="android/res/drawable-{sizes}/push_notification_icon.png" to replace those default icons.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your application icons with `push_notification_icon.png` in your android application-->drawable with same name.